# How to add dividers between items in a LazyColumn Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-list

I have a LazyColumn that looks like this:

```
LazyColumn (
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(12.dp)
) {
    items(bookList) { book ->
        InProgressBookItem(book = book)
    }
}
```

How can I add a line between each item in the list, similar to using an item decoration on the old RecyclerView?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Currently there is no built–in way to add dividers. However, you can just add a [`Divider`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#divider) in the [`LazyListScope`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/LazyListScope).

Something like:

```
LazyColumn(
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(12.dp),
) {
    items(itemsList){
        Text("Item at  $it")
        Divider(color = Color.Black)
    }
}
```

If you do not want the last item to be followed by a `Divider`, you can add dividers to items according to their indices:

```
LazyColumn(
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(12.dp),
) {
    itemsIndexed(itemsList) { index, item ->

        Text("Item at index $index is $item")

        if (index < itemsList.lastIndex)
            Divider(color = Color.Black, thickness = 1.dp)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This was my first thought, but I was hoping there would be a more elegant/built in way to do it.  For now, this should work, thank you!

Comment: Tip: instead of `index < itemsList.size-1` you can write `index < itemsList.lastIndex`

Comment: Or compose core team would have provided divider parameter that accepts Composable in LazyColumn function instead of forcing us do crappy workarounds like this

Comment: Tip: add divider before the item with condition `index>0`

Comment: What about `LazyRow`? This doesn't work with that

Answer (score 12):

Simple:

```
LazyColumn (
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(12.dp)
) {
    items(bookList) { book ->
        InProgressBookItem(book = book)
        Divider(color = Color.Black, thickness = 1.dp)
    }
}
```

Comment: Won't this add a divider after the final book too? I think the asker wanted them **only** in between elements.

Comment: It adds line after last item in the LazyColumn